# Retrieve scipy minimize function lowest error

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

Is there a way to directly retrieve the minimized error after scipy.minimize has converged or must that be directly coded into the cost function?

I can only retrieve the converged to coefficients it seems.

```
def errorFunction(params,series,loss_function,slen = 12):
    alpha, beta, gamma = params
    breakUps = int(len(series) / slen)
    end = breakUps * slen
    test = series[end:]
    errors = []

    for i in range(2,breakUps+1):
        model = HoltWinters(series=series[:i * 12], slen=slen,
                            alpha=alpha, beta=beta, gamma=gamma, n_preds=len(test))
        model.triple_exponential_smoothing()
        predictions = model.result[-len(test):]
        actual = test
        error = loss_function(predictions, actual)
        errors.append(error)
    return np.mean(np.array(errors))

opt = scipy.optimize.minimize(errorFunction, x0=x,
                   args=(train, mean_squared_log_error),
                   method="L-BFGS-B", bounds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
                  )
#gets the converged values
optimal values = opt.x
#I would like to know what the error with errorFunction is when using opt.x values, without having to manually run the script again
#Is the minimum error stored somewhere in the returned object opt
```

Comment: Can you please add your code? It's hard to help you without it :)

Comment: just added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from the documentation of the function `scipy.optimize.minimize`, the result is returned as a `OptimizeResult` object.

From the documentation of this class ([here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult)) it has an attribute `fun` that is the "values of objective function".

So if you do `opt.fun`, you should obtain the result you are looking for. (There are more values that you can retrieve like the Jacobian `opt.jac`, the Hessian `opt.hess`, ... as described in the documentation)